# Iterate over a dictionary and print results in a column with headers

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, format, iteration

I'm new to python and working my way through a few tutorials and Violent Python.

I'm trying to improve on an example in the book for a PW cracker.

I have the cracked passwords stored in a dict with the username as the key

results = {'user1 : pass1', user2 : pass2} etc...

I would like to iterate over the dictionary and print the results in the following way:

```
    key        User          Password
    1          user1         pass1
    2          user2         pass2
```

Below is the code I've been trying to use to get this to work along with the error I keep getting.

```
    print "{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}" .format("Key", "User", "Password")
    for k,v in results.iteritems():
        user, pw = v
        print  "{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}".format(v, user, pw)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "shadow_crack.py", line 75, in <module>
      main()
    File "shadow_crack.py", line 68, in main
     user, pw = v
    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results=dict(user1='pass1', user2='pass2')

print("{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}".format("Key", "User", "Password"))
for i, k in enumerate(sorted(results)):
    print("{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}".format(i+1, k, results[k]))
```

The above results in:

```
Key      User            Password
1        user1           pass1
2        user2           pass2
```

The error you were getting was because your dictionary `results = {'user1 : 'pass1', 'user2' : 'pass2'}`  had users as keys and passwords as values but did not have user numbers.  To generate user numbers above, I used enumerate to count over the sorted keys.

Dictionaries have the entries in undefined order.  So, to make a nice looking table, I sorted the keys so they will appear in order.

Comment: Not using iteritems here is kinda unpythonic imo.

Comment: @SteinarLima Any code that uses iteritems will break when run under Python3 where iteritems has been removed.

Comment: Yes, and this is Python 2.7. Use `items` if you consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to unpack the value of each key into two values, hence the error. What `.iteritems` does, is to return both the key and the value of your dict. The output you are trying to achieve, is an enumberation of your values. This code should help you on your way.

```
print "{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}" .format("Key", "User", "Password")
    for i, (user, pwd) in enumerate(results.iteritems()):
        print  "{:<8} {:<15} {:<15}".format(i, user, pwd)
```